# access vba DoCmd.OpenForm "Action was canceled"

Tags: forms, ms-access, parameter-passing, vba

```
Private Sub OccurrenceName_AfterUpdate()
If OccurrenceName.Value = "Other" Then
    Dim strTechID As String
    Dim strOccurrenceCt As String
    Dim strOccurrenceDate As String

    strTechID = Me.Parent.tbxTechID.Value
    strOccurrenceCt = Forms![frmEmployeeOccurrenceInput]![tbxOccurrence].Value
    strOccurrenceDate = Me.OccurrenceDate.Value

    Dim strOpenArgs As String
    strOpenArgs = strTechID & "|" & strOccurrenceCt & "|" & strOccurrenceDate

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmOtherOccurrence", , , , , , strOpenArgs
Else
    Me.OccurrenceAmt = Me.OccurrenceName.Column(1)
    Me.Type = Me.OccurrenceName.Column(2)
End If
End Sub
```

Every time it runs I get "The Open Form action was canceled" with an error code of 2501. The line it gets caught on is the `DoCmd.OpenForm` call.  Debugging give NO additional information.

Here is where the `OpenArgs` is passed to:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim aryOA As Variant

aryOA = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")

Me.lblTechID.Caption = aryOA(0)
Me.lblOccurrenceCt.Caption = aryOA(1)
Me.lblOccurrenceDate.Caption = aryOA(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Does frmOtherOccurrence open manually? What happens when you step through the code? Any code in the Open event? have you decompiled recently? Compacted & repaired?

Comment: After Compact and Repair it works... how often do I need to do that? Why would that cause things to not work...

Comment: Things get kept when you are developing and compact & repair clears them up. You need to back-up, decompile and compact & repair quite regularly while you are developing.

Comment: I'll have to remember that... thanks Remou -- you're helpful as always!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be your problem, but you can't pass OpenArgs to an open form, and by open I mean it can't be even in edit mode, should be completely closed.

Otherwise, the form will open (change its status from edit mode to normal) but no OpenArgs will be passed, so OpenArgs will be null and an exception will be thrown.